# i3 - How to prevent blank screen & auto lock?

Tags: i3-wm

How can I prevent my screen from going blank & auto-locking after some time when using i3 ?

I saw some people talking about modifying a .xinitrc file but I don't have such a file in my home directory.

Answer (score 2):

An .xinitrc file is one of many files that can be used to configure an xsession and can change depending on what desktop environment or window manager you are using. There is some good documentation here https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_Power_Management_Signaling on messing with xset which allows you to manually override settings configured elsewhere. One solution may be to put a line in your i3 config something like `exec --no-startup-id xset s off -dpms` which should disable screen blanking when your i3 instance is created.